# PDFBox Convert PDF to lower version

Tags: pdfbox

I have a program that outputs a PDF file using PDFBox (It merges a bunch of PDFs using PDFMergerUtility).

I need to use Acrobat 5 to read that PDF, but in some pages i get `Error proccesing page. A drawing error ocurred`.

I cant update my acrobat so, there is a way to *downgrade* the PDF using PDFbox?

Comment: You could set the appropriate version. But the real question is whether you are using operations that are not supported by that PDF version (Acrobat 5 supports up to 1.4). Finding and removing such operations would be a huge project. Or you'd create a new PDF that has only the image of the old one.

Comment: There is a guide about how to find such operations with pdfbox?
Sadly, making an image its not an option, the users need to copy from the PDF.

Comment: No there isn't. You'd have to read all PDF specifications from 1.4 up.